# Why in Boot loader most often written in assembly language?

Tags: boot-loader

I am studying the concept of **Operating system**. In that i read point of **Boot loader**. Why boot loader is most often written in **assembly language**.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about Unix.

Answer (score 4):

A boot loader needs to run in a very basic environment and needs to setup a lot of
hardware-near stuff. In old days, also the disk space for (at least some part of) the boot loader
was limited. Therefore it make sense, to program at least the initialization in assembler
where you have full control of the hardware and access to all CPU instructions.